# ListView, конец списка

Tags: android, listview

Как определить что список ListView прокручен до конца?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE 
            && (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() - listView.getHeaderViewsCount() -
            listView.getFooterViewsCount()) >= (adapter.getCount() - 1)) {

        // Now your listview has hit the bottom
    }
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

}
});
```

Comment: А как определить что прокручен обратно в начало?